# on click of Google Earth place marker balloons, shows html text. But Description box is empty

Tags: google-maps, gps, kml, google-earth, kmz

I have Converted a data from AutoCAD to KML in each placemark I can see html balloon text. But when I try to edit that data it is not showing in description box.

[image: Balloon]

[image: Description Box]

Answer (score 1):

The basic HTML table you're seeing in that balloon is auto-generated by Earth when it sees a KML that has attribute data (name/value pairs) in each Placemark's ExtendedData section, but has no balloon layout defined. So it's not encoded in the balloon description like most balloon layouts.

If you want to edit the balloon layout for that KML, then you can either type in your desired text or HTML into each balloon description box in Earth, or you can open up the KML file in a text editor and add a "BalloonStyle" section to a shared style that gets applied to one or more of the balloons.

In both cases (balloon layout in placemark description or in a shared style), you can take advantage of the ExtendedData values, with KML variables (placeholders) in your HTML.  For example, pulling in a couple of the values shown in your example balloon could look something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>EntityHandle: $[entities:EntityHandle]</h1>
  <p>Layer: $[entities:Layer]</p>
</body>
</html>
```

For more info on using ExtendedData and a shared BalloonStyle, see these documentation page:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle